# Javascript doesn't work for an image slider (help)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, transition

I'm quite new to this all, and I just need to have an image slider/transition full width for the top of my page..

only problem is; I've never used or did anything with javascript code writing.
I've been looking for about 5 hours now and tried every thing possible but I just can't make anything work.

Most of the time it's just images stacking up under each other or next to each other.

I'm using dreamweaver CC because I have a deadline for the website on thursday and it's easier.

As you may have read I'm completely useless when it comes to javascript..
Also, I'm quite confused about jquery.. (Yes, I've looked everywhere but I can't understand anything of it, no mather what I do.. it doesn't work)

Please help?

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous...adding some code might help.

Comment: What is your question exaclty?

Comment: The best way to start out is to do some javascript and jquery tutorials. This isn't really a write code for you website. nettuts is always good.

Comment: I just need a simpel basic image slider..

Comment: or image transition (I'm sorry, my native language is not english)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Slider</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function()
        {
                setInterval(function()
                {
                        var activeimg = $('#slider').find('img:visible:first'); 
                        (activeimg.next('img:hidden').parent().attr("id") == 'slider') ? 
                                activeimg.next('img:hidden').toggle("slow") : 
                                $('#slider').find('img:hidden:first').show("slow"); 
                        activeimg.toggle("slow"); 
                }, 3000);
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider">
        <img src="img/1.png">
        <img src="img/2.png" style="display:none;">
        <img src="img/3.png" style="display:none;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```